# How to combine in ffmpeg several jpeg files with several wav files?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have lot of jpeg file with names 01.jpeg - 225.jpeg and 10 wav files with names 17.wav - 26.wav. I need to combine them into video file with the duration of summary wav-files duration.
I tried to use command `ffmpeg -r 12 -start_number 1 -i %02d.jpg -start_number 17 -i %03d.wav -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4` and I got error: %03d.wav: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `concat demuxer` method from https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate for audio:

```
ffmpeg -r 12 -i %02d.jpg -f concat -safe 0 -i "list.txt" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -y output.mp4
```

The same for pics: pics from `01.jpg` to `99.jpg` is `%02d.jpg` and from `100.jpg` to `225.jpg` is `%03.jpg`. Sequence will not work. You can use method `concat demuxer` from  https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow or rename pics to 001.jpg etc.